# .NET 2.0 DateTime.ToString() conversion to different time zone

Tags: .net, timezone, utc

is there a format in ToString() method of DateTime to convert the time Zone to  say UTC ?

I know I can programatically first convert the DateTime to UTC and then call ToString,  but  I have a UI where the user can specify format, can they at the same time convert to UTC ?

Answer (score 4):

The .ToString("u") will format as UTC but not convert. This code below will convert and present the Date and Time in UTC format:

```
System.TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.ToUniversalTime(Date.Now).ToString("u")
```

or

```
DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime().ToString("u")
```

other formats can be [found here](http://idunno.org/archive/2004/14/01/122.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Not built in, but you can create your own formatter ([google IFormatProvider](http://www.google.com.au/search?sourceid=navclient&hl=en-GB&ie=UTF-8&rlz=1T4GGLJ_en-GBAU318AU318&q=IFormatProvider))

Answer (score 0):

No, you'll first have to convert the DateTime to the desired time zone.